# Error in finding the password in spring login form

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm writing a code where I can register people and allow them to login. Here I save details such as email and password of a customer who is a subclass of person. When I try to login with the given credentials, even though I give a valid email and a valid password it gives "Wrong Password!!" error. It is the same when I give valid username and an invalid password which is okay. It gives an error saying "No such email found!" when an invalid email is given, which is also fine.

Here is my customer controller which is associated with the issue.

```
         if(customer.getPassword() != existingCustomer.getPassword())
```

I want to make it possible that when I enter a valid password and a valid email, it redirects to viewCustomer. What is wrong with the above code? How can I fix it?

Comment: can you add code where you are calling this POST API `customerLogin` ?

Comment: Okay, I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to login with the given credentials, even though I give a valid email and a valid password it gives "Wrong Password!!"

Email is valid but you are comparing password in wrong way. Compare in this way:

```java
if(customer.getPassword().equals(existingCustomer.getPassword()))
```